# SOQL Like operator with %%% returns all records of given object

Tags: soql

If i run below query it returns all records of that object:

```
Select ID, name from Contact where Name like '%%%'
```

This should return only those records which have % in the name. For example if i run below query it will return only those records which have `test` in the name.

```
Select ID, name from Contact where Name like '%test%'
```

Any idea, What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to escape the percent sign like:

```
Select ID, name from Contact where Name like '%\%%'
```

Otherwise `%%%` would be treated same as `%%`

---

Found this in [SOQL documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm), never noticed before but now thanks to your question:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, right, I missed that. Thanks.